# Prevent fingerprinting on NGINX/nodejs AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My site is getting a lot of fingerprinting traffic on the IP address associated with my elastic load balancer. I'd like to disallow traffic on the IP address, similar to how IIS does site bindings.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you considered attaching an AWS Web Application Firewall to your load balancer? https://aws.amazon.com/waf/

Comment: Yes, this is what I would do if I had to implement it today. I was hoping there was a no-cost, no-complexity-added solution.

Comment: So you don't need to implement it today? I don't understand. I'm sure you could configure Nginx to reject the traffic, but that would still create some load on your server. WAF would block the traffic from ever getting to your server.

Comment: Amazon WAF is cheap. $5.00 for the Web ACL and $1.00 per rule plus traffic costs. The savings in CPU power on your instances may mean that you can reduce the instance size and actually save money with AWS WAF. We were able to take several WordPress instances from T2.large to T2.small after we added ALB + WAF. All the garbage traffic was gone.

Comment: You say *"I'd like to disallow traffic on the IP address"* but what you are really asking is how to configure nginx to reject traffic early based on what it finds (ip address or nonsense value) or doesn't find (the correct hostname for your site) in the incoming http `Host:` header... which of course can be done and will relieve your application of some unnecessary processing load.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for sharing your experience. I'll probably wind up going with WAF.

Comment: I don't think this will work for me, @Michael-sqlbot, as I don't have the ability to configure the NGINX instance used by the load balancer itself.

Comment: Which load balancer are you referring to that's running an "nginx instance?"

Comment: The AWS elastic load balancer. I thought I read somewhere they're running nginx under the hood.

Comment: I wondered if you were actually speaking of ALB.   This has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new target group.  Call it something obvious, like "blackhole."  Don't assign any instances to it.

Make the default rule of the ALB point to this target group.

Then, add a rule matching your correct/expected `Host` header, pointing to the real target group (with the instances).

Requests without that hostname in the `Host` header reach the default rule and are routed to its target group (the black hole), which has no instances.  The balancer rejects the request:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
```

Your instances see no traffic, unless the correct `Host` header is provided.